# Does Mailchimp notify for unsubscriptions?

Tags: email, mailchimp

I've had a few acquaintances + clients over the years adding me to their Mailchimp newsletters without my permission, and I could really do with cutting down the amount of emails that wind up in my inbox.

If I unsubscribe from their newsletters, will Mailchimp notify them? I have a feeling it would only notify them if I had actively subscribed to their newsletter myself, but thought I best make sure first.

Answer (score 0):

It *may* notify them. Within Mailchimp, the list owner can decide if they want email notifications for unsubscriptions.

By default this is off.